# What XML support salesforce provides in apex

Tags: xml, deserialize, serialization, serialize

(i) Is it possible to directly serialize/deserialize sObject record to xml in apex code?

(ii) Is it possible to serialize/deserialize apex object to/from xml?

Comment: Note that serialization to JSON is available through [JSON.serialize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_serialize) so if the serialization format is under your control I suggest your promote JSON as the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Answer for both questions is NO. At least directly.

Salesforce currently doesn't support direct serialisation of objects into XML format. You can only parse or create XML using `XMLDom` and `XMLStreamWriter`. So, as a work around you need to create xml nodes by writing xml using `XMLStreamWriter`.

**Another workaround:** I have this solution for a long time which serialise Sobjects. *It requires call out.* Not sure it still works but you can try it.

```
//Rest Service in Salesforce
@restresource(/urlmapping='/xmlSerializationSerivice/*') 
global class  XmlListExposer 
{

  @httpPost
  global static List<Account> getAccounts()
  {
     return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account limit 200];
  } 
}


// Webservice in Salesforce
global class XMLSerializationUtility
{

    webservice static staing getAccountsInXML()
    {

      Httprequest req=new Httpreques();
      req.setendpoint(URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/apexrest/xmlSerializationSerivice.xml');
      req.setmethod('POST');
      req.setheader('Authorization'.'OAuth '+userinfo.getsessionid());

      try
      {
        Http h=new Http();
        httpresponse r= h.send(req); 
        System.debug(''+r.getbody());
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
        System.debug(''+rex.getMessage());
      }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just so that someone may benefit from it, I wrote XML serializer which can serialize/deserialize apex objects to and from XML. Check it out here: https://github.com/skolakan/Apex-XML-Serializer